# How to integrate HTML 5 for BlackBerry, IOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, html, blackberry

i am doing some work on HTML5. I want to run that html 5 on BlackBerry, IOS and Android is it possible to run that code on all these three platform. and how to make it runnable application file of that project i.e. `.bar(BlackBerry) .apk(android)  .app(ios)`

Thanks in advance...

Comment: This is General Question. you need to go through Assignments of the same.

Comment: this is already supported in all the browsers of all these mobile os..!! Use phonegap api.

Answer (score 3):

I think you didn't heard about **PHONE GAP**  cross platform software.
here is link for the tutorial basic into every field .there you have to apply your HTML5 work .

And it will be help full to you for others platform also.

[Iphone](http://phonegap.com/start)

[Android](http://phonegap.com/start#android)

[Blackberry](http://phonegap.com/start#blackberry)

Comment: @sayali its seems great that my ans help you.If you require any help for this "phone Gap" . let me write freely...

Answer (score 0):

Use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com) platform.It will help you to create cross-platform code.

Comment: You can also use Titanium for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You may use one of the software [RhoStudio](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhostudio.tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

go through this Docs [PhoneGap API Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android)
They have given docs for all Android,Blackberry and iphone. follow the steps and you will get it solution for sure. All The best!!

Comment: Again please try to run on real device because it may not work properly on emulator..

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap is really good!

However you may also try Intel XDK! 
It's provides a smooth interface to develop HTML 5 apps running on native platforms!
A complete setup of the app development process is provided & various demos are also provided to help development!